# How to design rest uri for the particular case?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

I have a list of employees manage by rest api thru EmployeeController.

Few URIs-

```
/employees - Get all employees

/employees/1 - Get employee with id 1
```

Employee has an object Department which has **deptId**.

Now i want to create URI to **get all the employees which has deptId = 30 and dateofBirth > '01-01-1990'**

What will be the best way to write URI for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common practise to use query parameter on `/employees` to filter which employee will be returned .

For example :

- `/employees?deptId=30` to only return employees whose department is
  30
- `/employees?dateofBirth=19900101` to only return employees whose
  DOB is on 1st-Jan-1990
- `/employees?deptId=30&dateofBirth=19900101` to
  return employees whose satisfy the above conditions at the same time.

Comment: GET parameter are mandatory by default. So don't forget to set the `required=false` attribute in the annotation if they should be optional.

Comment: @Ken i have a different condition. I don't want all employees whose dob is 1990101. i want who are born (> ) later than 19900101.

Comment: For `>` , it is very opinionated and subject to the personal preference. You can check [this](https://www.google.com/search?ei=SaJbXeLVMYuEoAS4nLeIAw&q=rest+api+design+greater+than&oq=rest+api+design+greater+than&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0..2006...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.xcT8HA2LJgc&ved=0ahUKEwiinsvI95DkAhULAogKHTjODTEQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) to reference how other are implementing it and try the one that make sense to the team. Or how about `/employees?afterDateofBirth=19900101` ?

Comment: Thanks Ken.  1 quick question, can't we have (-) in dateofbirth query parameter?

Comment: Sure . YYYMMDD is just my personal preference   .You can use `DD-MM-YYYY` if you like